# Title for Tabbed Panel in wicket

Tags: wicket

I am working with `TabbedPanel` in wicket. I have created a `TabbedPanel` for my search page

[image: this is how my tabbedpanel looks like]

My requirement is to create a `TabbedPanel` with title and three tabs. I am using additional tab (`Dummytab` in this case) to compensate the title. Please, suggest me how to create a title tab.

First tab is dummy tab and it is active. I want the `Search 1` tab to be default tab and `Search:` tab to be inactive and just represent the title for the `TabbedPanel`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want it this way? This is a non-standard UI element, and it is better to stick to UI patters that people already know.

Comment: Hey RobAu i am newbie and donot have great understanding of either wicket or UI patterns. I just had an idea and started off with it. if u have better approach and share i'd appriciate it. Thanks

Comment: Hey Uday, it's good to start somewhere :) Just to let you know, there is already a lot of work done on finding out what a good interface is for users. For tabs, tabs normally do not contain a title for all tabs in the same row, the title of each tab should be enough. If you need a title, put it above. See also here: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/tabs-used-right/

Comment: And besides the above comment,  it also takes less work :) (but your question is nice, it gives you an opportunity to figure out how to customize Wicket's components and have some fun along the way as well)

Comment: Thanks RobAu the link provides great prospective and i am starting to work on alternate approachs. appriciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative: subclass TabbedPanel and provide your own custom markup.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can simply override `TabbedPanel`'s `newLink` method to replace real link via some container for first tab. It would be something like that:

```java
TabbedPanel tp = new TabbedPanel (...) {
{
    @Override
    protected WebMarkupContainer newLink(final String linkId, final int index)
    {
        return (index > 0) ? super.newLink(linkId, index) :
                                           new WebMarkupContainer (linkId);
    }
};
tp.setSelectedTab( 1 ); // selecting `Search 1` tab after tp creation;
```

Also, if you want to prevent selecting first tab programmaticaly - you should play around with overriding `setSelectedTab` method.

Comment: Thank You. Exactly what i needed and extra. Started working around setSelectedTab.

Comment: It's my pleasure. You should also take into account RobAu's suggestion. I like your design, but may be it is not very convenient for end-user in practice.

Comment: Thank you  Michael Zhavzharov. i did consider that suggestion from RobAu and started working on different approach. Thank You